# Eigen aliasing return value optimization

Tags: c++, eigen

Suppose I define a function returning an `Eigen::MatrixXd` by value, such as

```
Eigen::MatrixXd f(const Eigen::MatrixXd& in)
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd tmp = in; // copy the input
    // do something here with tmp
    return tmp;
}
```

which I then use like

```
Eigen::MatrixXd A;
A = f(A);
```

As far as I understand, there is no aliasing danger here, as `f(A)` returns a temporary that is then being assigned to `A`. However, most compilers perform return value optimization (RVO), and the temporary is built directly in `A`. In this case, can I get into trouble with the assignment `A = f(A);`? In the code I wrote things seem to work fine, however I'd like to know if this assignment is indeed safe all the time.

Comment: *"and the temporary is constructed directly in A"* -- No it's not. That's an assignment, not a construction. While RVO may apply for constructing the return value of the function directly from `tmp`, copy elision cannot eliminate the assignment from the return value to `A`.

Comment: You never have to worry about RVO introducing unexpected behavior unless you have weird side-effects in your copy or move constructors. Remember, with the exception of not calling a constructor, RVO behaves exactly the same as-if RVO wasn't a thing.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I used the wrong term, I meant built directly into `A`, since this is what's happening in case of RVO if I am not wrong.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley hmm, so basically I get an extra copy due to action of the assignment operator, is this correct? I'd like to optimize this step, but Eigen does not yet support move semantics, so probably the best is to use the swap function instead of the assignment operator. In other words, I would like to pay only once for copying the input in `f()`.

Comment: @vsoftco: You could just take the object by non-const reference and modify it directly.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley this is a problem, as in general I do not want to modify the input parameter. Thanks for clarifying the RVO business. But I guess there is no way to get it done with less than 2 copies.